# Equivalence of defintion for Markov Property

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation, markov-process

I've seen definitions of Markov Property for a process $X$ indexed with the positive integers with values in $S$, that are supposedly equavalent. I consider the canonical filtration $\mathcal F=(\mathcal F_n)_{n\geq 0}$ generated by the process.

$1)\ \ \mathbb P(X_{n+1}=s\ \ |\mathcal F_n)=\mathbb P(X_{n+1}=s|X_n)$

$2)\ \ \mathbb E[f(X_{n+1})|\mathcal F_n]=\mathbb E[f(X_{n+1})|X_n]$ for all bounded functions $f:S\rightarrow \mathbb R$.

$2\rightarrow 1$ holds trivially on finite $S$. But what is the idea in the general case?

Do I have to go through the usual thing of first proving it for indicator functions, simple functions and limits of simple functions and dominated convergence? Or is there a simpler way?

Comment: Where did you read that (1) is an equivalent definition of the Markov property of a process?

Comment: I'm sorry, i was thinking of indicator functions, but didn't write it... I corrected it above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any bounded map $f:S\to\mathbb R$ and $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal G$,
$$
\mathbb E[f(X_{n+1})\vert\mathcal G]=\sum_{s\in S}f(s)\mathbb P(X_{n+1}=s\vert\mathcal G),
$$
from which you can easily deduce the equivalence.